# How to use the non-unicode glyphs

Tags: fonts, unicode

In some OpenType fonts e.g. XITS Math, there are some non-unicode glyphs. For example, the "display integral" glyph has the same code point (U+222B) as the normal integral. Although the big int can be used with `\displaystyle`, but how to use it directly (like `\symbol{...}`)?

Both XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX solutions are welcome.

**Update:**

Using XITS Math as an example. At the end of unicode block, there are a lot of glyph variants with name as `unixxxx.yyy`. `xxxx` here is the code point, while `yyy` is the variants name. For example, `uni222B.display` is the big integral with unicode value -1 and glyph index 3584 (0xE00). Obviously, using it's unicode value as `\symbol{-1}` will not give the correct symbol.

Definitely, with commands like `\displaystyle`, one can easily get access to the big integral symbol. However, how can I use the other symbols, like `u1D49C.cal` (script A) and `uni221D.rtlm` (right to left form propotional)?

Although there are speific tricks to use there symbol, to access all these symbols uniformly is also very useful (e.g. creating a font table).

Comment: Would it be ok to write a macro to invoke mathmode, displaystyle and the integral? Such as `\newcommand{\myintegral}{$\displaystyle\char"222B$}`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is the xetex version  luaotfload can do similar

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}


\font\xm="XITS Math/OT:script=math;language=DFLT;" at 20pt


\begin{document}

\xm 
^^^^222b 
\XeTeXglyph\XeTeXglyphindex "uni222B" 
\XeTeXglyph\XeTeXglyphindex "uni222B.up" 
\XeTeXglyph\XeTeXglyphindex "uni222B.small" 
\XeTeXglyph\XeTeXglyphindex "uni222B.display" 
\XeTeXglyph 3584


\end{document}
```

You can see the variant glyph names by looking in the font's MATH table with fontforge or a similar tool.

Answer (score 4):

Under either XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX, all you need to do is write `\char"222B`. The size of the integral symbol will depend on whether it occurs in text mode, text-style math mode, or display-style math mode.

[image]

```
%% Compile with either XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{XITS}
\setmathfont{XITS Math}

\begin{document}
\char"222B{} $\char"222B$ $\displaystyle \char"222B$
\end{document}
```

Comment: What I want is a *directly* way to use the glyph, i.e. do not use `\displaystyle` and even math environment. By the way, there are other symbols like italic double-struck letters that can not be used with `\displaystyle`.

Answer (score 3):

A LuaTeX version:

```
\documentclass{article}

\font\xm="XITS Math/OT:script=math;language=DFLT;" at 20pt

\newcommand\LuaTeXglyphindex{\directlua{
  tex.sprint(0, font.getfont(font.current()).resources.unicodes[token.scan_string()])
}}
\begin{document}

\xm 
\char"222B 
\char\LuaTeXglyphindex uni222B.small
\char\LuaTeXglyphindex uni222B.display
\char\LuaTeXglyphindex uni222B.up
\char\LuaTeXglyphindex uni222B.up.display
\char\LuaTeXglyphindex uni222B.rtlm
\char\LuaTeXglyphindex uni222B.rtlm.display

\end{document}
```

[image]