# How can I select one No-unicode symbol from one font?

Tags: fonts, luatex, fontspec, unicode, font-encodings

I am using Asea font http://users.teilar.gr/~g1951d/Textfonts.zip

From http://users.teilar.gr/~g1951d/

And I want to pick some characters that are not encoded in unicode, but are present in the font, like these:

[image]

The alpha with macron and smooth breathing  appear in position "1114698 (0x11024a)" (I saw at FontForge), but does not have an unicode  (U + XXXX) number. How can I select this symbol using fontspec package (the \symbol command)?

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98188/how-can-i-access-a-specific-glyph-in-lualatex-fontspec (although Ulrike Fischer came up with a great answer specific to your question, so it’s not really a duplicate).

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/420167.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The glyphs can be accessed through a ligature with the macron accent (U+0304):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Asea.ttf}[Script=Greek]
\begin{document}
ᾱ^^^^0304 ά^^^^0304 ὰ^^^^0304 ἀ^^^^0304 ἁ^^^^0304 ἄ^^^^0304 ἂ^^^^0304 
ἅ^^^^0304 ἃ^^^^0304
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: While that works for this particular font, what if there were no ligature combination to access it?  (unlikely but, that would make the answer a lot more general, if it's possible)

Comment: @guifa there is no general answer. It depends on the font how glyph can be accessed - sometimes such glyphs are stylistic variants, here they are used in ligatures.

Comment: It's also possible to store glyphs in a font without having a way to access them via ligatures, variants, etc, and thus only access than by glyph ID.  That would be the general answer, but I don't know if fontspec gives that level of access.

Comment: @guifa you can do `\char 983627` (with luatex, xelatex would need some other number) you can also access by glyphname.