# How do I get different glyphs in a font via commands?

Tags: fonts, symbols, unicode

In the `ebgaramond` package there are several glyphs as indicated in the [pdf on ctan](http://mirrors.ctan.org/fonts/ebgaramond/doc/EBGaramond-Regular-Glyphs.pdf) which gives the code for each glyph. I know commands for some of the glyphs such as `\copyright` `\textonehalf` `\textsection` etc. But how do I access rest of the glyphs via commands? For example, in the [ETBB package](http://mirrors.ctan.org/fonts/etbb/doc/ETbb-doc.pdf) documentation pages 5-7 contains such list (see the image below). One way might be as suggested [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/420167/how-to-use-the-non-unicode-glyphs) using the code directly. But is there an **already existing** list of commands somewhere which can be used to access these glyphs in general for any font?

[image]

Comment: generally you can always use `\char190 ` to access the char in position 190 (which one this is depends on the encoding). The names you show in your screenshot are quite standard and predefined in a current LaTeX and should normally work.